# Python 2.4 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, python

I want to develop a Python application on Ubuntu 12.04 using python 2.4, but since the default version of python on ubuntu is 2.7. I cannot get the libraries and packages to work for python 2.4. I have tried using virtualenv but even with virtualenv I was not successful in installing packages for python2.4.

So I would like to know if there is any reliable method to get python 2.4 to work with Ubuntu. I know that I shouldnt mess with the default version of python on ubuntu and hence I am looking for a better alternative.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why on earth would you use 2.4? You make more work for yourself, you have less features, and I don't think 2.4 even gets security patches any more. And anything you write for 2.4 should work in 2.7 anyway, so long as you avoid calling a variable `with`.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 options:

- Download from python.org and compile it yourself. In your homefolder for example to not mess with system files.
- Add the following PPA. I have no idea how it handles already installed versions though. https://launchpad.net/~fkrull/+archive/deadsnakes?field.series_filter=precise

And, I must ask: why 2.4? That version is **ancient**!

Edit: To install modules/packages for that version, you can't just use the ones from the Ubuntu repository. You'll need to get them from their website and do the regular `python setup.py install` and make sure you use the Python 2.4 interpreter.
A bit easier probably is to use `pip`, but again, use it with the correct Python interpreter.

Comment: I have python2.4 already installed from the ppa. But I am having  tough time getting the libraries for 2.4 and that is the only reason for the question.

Comment: Aha, got it. See my edit.